# Windows authentication fails without running as administrator

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication, active-directory

The application, not ASP.NET, uses the below code to authenticate with windows.

Run the application as a normal process and it fails to authenticate with either local machine or domain. "The handle is invalid" is the exception for local machine.

Run it as administrator and it works fine for both domain and machine. Any idea?

It did use to work fine for both, so it is not impossible that there was a policy change in the security settings.

```
private bool VerifyWindowsPassword()
{
    bool ret = false;
    string username = this.usernameTextBox.Text;
    string unsecure = ConvertToUNSecureString(this.Password);

    try
    {
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        try
        {
            ret = context.ValidateCredentials(username, unsecure);
            if (ret)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
        ret = context.ValidateCredentials(username, unsecure);
        if (ret)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!ret)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Windows User/Password could not be authenticated.",
                "Settings",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
               string.Format("Windows User/Password could not be authenticated. {0}", ex.Message),
               "Settings",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK,
               MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? `ValidateCredentials()`?

Comment: When you don't run it as admin, are you still running it under domain credentials?

Comment: Yeah ValidateCredentials thows the exception for ContextType.Machine. I am logged into the domain and running the application from my domain user.

Comment: Do both throw the exception, or only the second one?

Comment: Domain fails nicely with false, second one with Machine throws exception